# compare two arrays with not all similar entries and store similar components in third array ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array arrAll which has a dictionary at each index. 
So, arrAll is of the form

```
arrAll = ({"id"=1,"type"="first",},{"id"=2,"type"="second"},{"id"=3,"type"="third"},{"id"=4,"type"="fourth"});
```

I have another array named arrSelected.

```
arrSelected = (second,fourth);
```

Now, what i have to do is pick the dictionaries containing 'second' & 'fourth' as their type and store them in my third array, say, arrFiltered.
So ultimately arrFiltered should contain

```
arrFiltered = ({"id"=2,"type"="second"},{"id"=4,"type"="fourth"});
```

It could be easily done using conventional method of looping. I want to ask if there is any other way out to get it done using PREDICATE or something like INTERSECTSET?

Comment: Is arrSelected = (second,fourth); strings?

Comment: you need answer on swift or obj c?

Comment: What language are the examples? If this is Swift there are no arrays, only tuples and dictionaries. I think that in Objective-C it won't even compile.

Comment: Give a real working example and decide on a language.

Comment: I need an answer on objective-c.

Answer (score 2):

For Swift you are looking for something like:

```
let arrAll: [[String: Any]] = [
        ["id": 1, "type": "first"],
        ["id": 2, "type": "second"],
        ["id": 3, "type": "third"],
        ["id": 4, "type": "fourth"]
    ]

let arrSelected = ["second", "fourth"]

let arrFiltered = arrAll.filter() {
    guard let type = $0["type"] as? String else { return false }
    return arrSelected.contains(type)
}

print(arrFiltered) // [["id": 2, "type": "second"], ["id": 4, "type": "fourth"]]
```

Comment: swift is somthng i can't comprehend. I tagged swift by mistake. Can u plz post objective-c equivalent of ur code.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Swift version emanating from `arrSelected` rather than `arrAll`. Pre-requisite that the value for key `"type"` is unique in each dictionary in the array (otherwise: just collects first such dictionary):

```
let arrAll : [[String:Any]] = [
    ["id": 1, "type": "first"],
    ["id": 2, "type": "second"],
    ["id": 3, "type": "third"],
    ["id": 4, "type": "fourth"]]

let arrSelected = ["second","fourth"]

/* Alternative Swift method: from arrSelected -> filtered */
let arrFiltered = arrSelected.flatMap {
    v in arrAll.flatMap { ($0["type"] as? String) == v ? $0 : nil }.first
}

print(arrFiltered)
    /* [["id": 2, "type": "second"], ["id": 4, "type": "fourth"]] */
```

Comment: swift is somthng i can't comprehend. I tagged swift by mistake. Can u plz post objective-c equivalent of ur code.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code for objective-C by using conventional looping method

```
    NSMutableArray * arrFiltered =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i=0; i<arrAll.count; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *dictFirst=[arrAll objectAtIndex:i];
        for (int j=0; j< arrSelected.count; j++)
        {
            NSString *strSecond=[arrSelected objectAtIndex:j];
            if ([[dictFirst valueForKey:@"type"]isEqualToString:strSecond])
            {
                [arrFiltered addObject:[arrAll objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Flitered Array= %@",arrFiltered);
```

you can also you predicate to get filtered array by using below code

```
 NSMutableArray * arrFiltered =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 for (int j=0; j< arrSelected.count; j++)
 {
        NSString *strSecond=[arrSelected objectAtIndex:j];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type =%@",strSecond];
        NSArray *arrTemp=[arrAll filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        [arrFiltered addObjectsFromArray:arrTemp];
  }
  NSLog(@"Flitered Array= %@",arrFiltered);
```

Comment: I have already mentioned the typical code. I need to know if this could be done using predicate or intersection

Comment: thanks 4 ur effort. But above code is not working. 'arrAll' contain 'type' within a dictionary. So, directly applying 'filteredArrayUsingPredicate' result in an empty 'arrTemp' array.